# How to shortcut a coroutine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I wrote a co-routine to do batch work every frame, I have no problem starting it, but I want to stop the execution when specific conditions are met.

Such as :

```
public  IEnumerator workCoroutine(){
    int i = 0;

    if(GLOBAL_LOCK){
      return; //will not work here.
     //we will not execute this coroutine further more, ie,shortcut it;
     //but how to ?
    }
    while( i<=1000){
       doingSomeWorkHere(i);
       i++;
       yield return null;
    }
}
```

I know I could maybe do this by:

```
public  IEnumerator workCoroutine(){
    int i = 0;

    if(!GLOBAL_LOCK){
       while( i<=1000){
         doingSomeWorkHere(i);
         i++;
         yield return null;
       }
    }  
}
```

But I think this way may cause the code to get ugly when there are multiple conditions.

So is there a way to cut off the co-routine?

### EDIT

I really don't understand what people are saying in the comments, here is a fully functioning test script, will somebody point out how to test if the co-routine has exited? or give me some material to read on?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestCoroutine : MonoBehaviour {


    private bool GLOBAL_LOCK = true;

    public IEnumerator workCoroutine()
    {
        int i = 0;

        if (!GLOBAL_LOCK)
        {
            while (i <= 10)
            {
                Debug.Log(i);
                i++;
                yield return null;
            }
            Debug.Log(" I am in if condition");
        }
        Debug.Log(" will exit the coroutine");
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine(workCoroutine());
    }
}
```

Comment: Both code are wrong. Even the second code you think is working is not. If the while loop is running and `GLOBAL_LOCK` becomes true, it won't even detect it because the `if` statement is outside the `while` loop and will be checked only **once**. Just like your other question, please test your script before posting it in your question and claiming it is doing something that it is not really doing. This can cause many people to leave wrong answers and back and forth comments.

Comment: @Programmer I have tested this code, Check the `GLOBAL_LOCK` once was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: You want to exit the function if the GLOBAL_LOCK is true, right? That second second won't exit when GLOBAL_LOCK becomes true while it is still in the while loop. It shouldn't work as you are saying. That if statement should be inside the while loop. My comment is telling you that the second code should not work like you claimed that it works

Comment: @Programmer How come when `GLOBAL_LOCK ` is true, the second snippet won't exit? have just tested that again.

Comment: _"How come when `GLOBAL_LOCK` is true, the second snippet won't exit"_ -- because the second snippet won't exit, ever. A better question would be "how come when `GLOBAL_LOCK` is false, the second snippet won't exit?", because it won't, and it won't for the same reason the first snippet won't exit. If you want your method to exit, it needs to check `GLOBAL_LOCK` each iteration of the loop, e.g. `while (!GLOBAL_LOCK && i <= 1000) ...`

Comment: @PeterDuniho could you give some advice to show that the second snippet won't exits? check the EDIT, it only prints `will exit the coroutine`.

Comment: But it only exits the coroutine when the loop index reaches 10 (or 1000) in your original example. Your question appears to be asking how to have it exit _early_, which it does not in either snippet you originally provided, nor the edited version. If you aren't asking how to use the `GLOBAL_LOCK` flag to cause the coroutine to exit early, then I have no idea what you're asking. Your question is unclear and needs to be improved.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I thought the second snippet and the EDIT I give are the same. Aren't they?

Comment: Well, they are obviously not _identical_. But they are the same, in that the `GLOBAL_LOCK` has no effect on the loop once it's begun. I posted in my first comment above the change you would need to make if you want the `GLOBAL_LOCK` flag to cause the loop to exit early.

Comment: @armnotstrong Look at Mukesh's answer. I could've left an answer but I don't think you will learn from that. I believe what you do is post some random code and expect people to write your code for you. I suggest you learn basic loop structure or you will have hard time. Finally, make sure your code is doing what say is doing before posting. The comment section get's long if you don't. You know you can accept answers? I think you should start doing that. Mukesh's answer should fix your problem.

Comment: @Programmer I am very appetite with @Mukesh's answer, although, if my second snippet /the EDIT works, I will gain more elegant code and also do less compression with the `GLOBAL_LOCK `,  I apologize if I didn't do a test (case it's not very convenient when I ask that question when IDE is not available) on the last question(which I found it's another issue case the problem so just delete that), but you should stop presuming me *just post some random code and expect people to write your code for you*, and should also stop being so arrogant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check for the GLOBAL_LOCK inside while loop as follows -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestCoroutine : MonoBehaviour {


    private bool GLOBAL_LOCK = true;

    public IEnumerator workCoroutine()
    {
        int i = 0;

        while (i <= 10)
        {
            if (GLOBAL_LOCK)
            {
                Debug.Log(" I am in if condition");
                Debug.Log(" will exit the coroutine");
                yield break;
            }else{
                Debug.Log(i);
                i++;
                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine(workCoroutine());
    }
}
```

This code will print the Log statements from `if` condition and exit the coroutine because `GLOBAL_LOCK` is set to `true`.

Comment: HI, thanks for your answer,  so `yield break` will break the coroutine loop from further execution, right?

Comment: Yes, `yield break` will stop further execution of coroutine. :)

Comment: thanks, just have tested, that's all what I wanted. :D

Comment: Furthermore, if I put `yield break;` outside the `while` loop(just put it in the place of `return;` in the first snippet) such as `if(GLOBAL_LOCK){yield break;}`, will not gain any problem right? Because people in comment are really confusing me :D

Comment: That will work fine but the behavior will be different. It'll check for GLOBAL_LOCK only once at starting of coroutine, if GLOBAL_LOCK is false at that time then while loop will start executing untill (i<=1000). During while loop execution it won't check if GLOBAL_LOCK value is changed to true.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, it's my fault that didn't explain the question clear, maybe it's my bad English that to blame :D, in my case a once check is good enough, good day!

Answer (score 0):

Beside @MukeshSaini, answer you can also stop execution of your coroutine using [**StopCoroutine**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html) Function.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestCoroutine : MonoBehaviour {


    private bool GLOBAL_LOCK = true;
    // keep a copy of the executing script
    private IEnumerator coroutine;
    public IEnumerator workCoroutine()
    {
        int i = 0;

        while (i <= 10)
        {            
                Debug.Log(i);
                i++;
                yield return null;
        }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine(workCoroutine());
    }


    void Update() {
        if (GLOBAL_LOCK )//your specific condition
        {
        StopCoroutine(coroutine);

        }
    }

}
```

Advantage: This will allow you to stop your coroutine from any place, i provide example with update